# How to check Docker RAM and cores configuration from terminal? (MacOS)

Tags: macos, docker, terminal

I would like to find out what are the max RAM and cores available to a new docker container.  Using Docker GUI, I can click on the Docker icon, then going to Preferences --> Advanced.  Two sliders show up, and the values selected on the sliders, are the values I am interested in.  However, I can not use the GUI and want to find out via terminal.  Is this possible?

(Note - I am not interested in *modifying* these values, only discovering what they are, via terminal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I came across this:

find $HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker  -type f -name '*.json' | xargs jq -r .arguments

(jq is just a utility which will let you manipulate/parse about the json.  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ . .  That file itself is not very readable.)

You will see entries in the json:

```
  "-c",
  "5",
  "-m",
  "4096M",
```

This corresponds to the current values you'd see on the sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
docker inspect container_name
```

Comment: unfortunately, it might be that the user has no docker containers set up at this point, and I can not make one prior to getting this information

Comment: If there is no better approach @ffConundrums, you could use a dummy container that is always running, and then just `inspect` that.

Comment: do you know what would be a super simple docker container?  i am trying to avoid having to download an image just for this purpose.  unfortunate that there seems to be no alternative to this.

Comment: I'm also not certain this is giving me the information I would like.  Will the value given to the dummy container always be the max?  I do not even see an entry for cores in 'docker inspect'